# How to add programs to the Open With dialog on Windows7

Tags: windows-7, file-association, sublime-text-3

I'm trying to associate files with specific programs and Sublime Text 3 is not in the dialog as an option nor can I select it after browsing for the C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3\sublime_text.exe. It just goes exits the dialog entirely.

I am currently the administrator and have ST3 running as admin also.

So how can I add sublime Text to this dialog for all future file type assignments?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Windows will show all programs it thinks can open a particular file type.  You followed the right procedure to use an unlisted program.  A couple of things to check that can cause the behavior you're seeing.

- Make sure that sublime_text.exe is the main executable, not a component that gets called from something else and that it is working.  Double click on it an see if it launches and opens what you expect to see.
- Verify that it can be opened with command line arguments that allow a file to be passed to it.  Some programs aren't designed to work this way; you have to launch them and then open the file from the program. Programs of this type won't work even if you get them to appear in the list.

Comment: Thanks @Fixer1234 yes I'm trying to launch txt and code files with Sublime Text, a popular code editor. I'm totally stumped.